# Erik Reinert's conclusions and experiments in economics

Tags: reference-request, poverty, experimental-economics, migration

I have just read [Erik Reinert's, "How Rich Countries Got Rich… and Why Poor Countries Stay Poor"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1586486683). Can anybody advise me some further reading on this topic? I wonder, in particular,

- if there were investigations on the influence of the international specialization of labour on the migration processes?
- if there were [experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_economics) in this field?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's been too long since I read those, so I don't exactly remember  whether they answer your two specific questions, but if you are interested in the topic you should definitely have a look at:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bottom_Billion
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Bottom_Billion

and the corresponding TED talk at

- http://www.ted.com/talks/paul_collier_shares_4_ways_to_help_the_bottom_billion?language=en

Comment: while it's helpful to provide links, answers really have to be self-contained. At the moment, this text doesn't provide any answer to the question: it just advises readers to go elsewhere. What we're trying to do is build up a body of great content here, supplemented by signposts to knowledge elsewhere.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers : I agree with you in principle. For instance, I think I could have made more effort on a recent answer at http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8214/who-owns-german-debt/8222#8222‌​. I did not have much time then and thought it was better than nothing. This being said, because the current question is specifically tagged as a "reference-request", I thought links would be enough (although I admitedly only answer the "Can anybody advise me some further reading on this topic?" part of the question). Anyways, I would understand any opinion otherwise ans subsequent downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If Reinert's central claim is that protectionist trade policies promote economic growth, the only empirical evidence I've seen points in exactly the opposite direction. That would be Xavier Sala-i-Martin's papers on growth accounting, such as "The Economic Tragedy of the XXth Century: Growth in Africa".

http://www.nber.org/papers/w9865

Comment: I must say, I did not understand your point.